# vba match and set value of column next to it

Tags: excel, vba, match

many iterations Ive seen and googled, but I would like to change to column to the matched value row in one line, but somehow cant make it work.
Can anyone share some thoughts on the match/vlookup formula below, and why it gives a "unable to get the match property of the worksheet function class" error?

```
Dim swl As Long
Dim var1 As Long
var1 = 3
swl = 250
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("g2:h8")

Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(var1, rng, 1), 2).Value = swl
'''
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it in one line, to avoid errors such as yours, but MATCH requires a 1d array (and last parameter is 0 for exact match). You could use Find instead.

Comment: great tip, didnt realise match is only for a1d array,it works if I change the array, find will be the better function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before:

[image]

some code:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim swl As Long
    Dim var1 As Long
    
    var1 = 3
    swl = 250
    Dim rng As Range, gotit As Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("g2:h8")
    Set gotit = rng.Find(what:=var1)
    
    If gotit Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        gotit.Offset(0, 1).Value = swl
    End If
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: perfect, almost one line! just need to insert a check since if the same value (3) is higher up in the second column it will change that, but that can be easily changed by limiting the array to that one column. Thanks for your help!